# How to stop reload the data from db for every request?

Tags: jsf

I loaded the data from db and set to beans. It diplay in screen. Suppose if i click any button in same screen, the data loaded again from db. All beans are null for every request. That is the reason i am unable to stop the loading. Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue?

I wrote code like this

```
public class Bean {

private Service service;

private String email;

private String name;

public void setService(final Service newService) {
if(this.service == null)
{
this.service = newService;
try {       
//load data from db set the values of email and name                          
 this.service.createContact(this);
} catch (SQLException e) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

### facess-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
<description>The bean to manage service.</description>
<managed-bean-name>Bean</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>com.bean.Bean</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
<managed-property>
<property-name>Service</property-name>
<value>#{service}</value>
</managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: Are your beans declared with Request scope or Session scope?

Answer (score 2):

Your bean is declared with request scope. That means, it gets created new for each request. Quite apart from that: `if(this.service == null)` will *always* be true because the setter gets called only once when the bean is created (no matter what scope it has).

If you're sure the data will never change between requests, simply declare the bean with session scope, and it will be created once per user session, or application scope to have it created once for the entire application.

Comment: Thank you. But it is working, but it does't load from db upto logout. For example If i go back to screen, i want to load again from DB. if i clink any button in same screen then don't reload from db.

Comment: @venkat: in that case, you'd want the view scope introducted in JSF 2. But be aware that this means your bean's contents will be serialized and saved as hidden parameters in the page itself. This can cause quite a few problems. The alternative is to use session scope but find a way to detect on-page navigation and don't reload the data only in that case.

Comment: Saved as hidden parameter is only true when state saving is set to `client` instead of (default) `server`. And this does not apply to view scoped beans specifically.

Comment: @BalusC: Hm, I'm not setting explicitly anywhere, and I get Exceptions when the bean is not Serializable (and this does not happen with session and application scoped beans). I'm using MyFaces.

Comment: View scoped beans are stored in component tree which in turn get serialized in session. The only hidden parameter is `javax.faces.ViewState` which is basically the session attribute key of the component tree.

Comment: @BalusC: Ah, that explains it. And means my point is still valid: view scoped beans need to be serializable, which means, for example, that that "service" managed property is going to be problematic.

Comment: Yes true, your point is still valid :) Just wanted to rectify an invalid comment.